# Magento Create New Customer Not Working

Tags: customer-account

When trying to create a new customer on the [frontend](http://dev.bivouacannarbor.com/customer/account/create/), Magento does not alert the user that an account already exists with that email address. I'm not seeing anything in system.log and cannot figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There was a conflict with another extension (custom attributes for customers). After reviewing the module's code, I was able to fix my issue.